# Java: How do I acess variables belonging to another class that change so I dont have to re-make the object again and again

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor

I am new to Java. I am writing a programme that requires some code to access another class' variables, however the variables change and the object is only returning the variables that were initialised. How would I go about this [preferably provide example code please].

Comment: Welcome to SO @James.  I'm sorry to see you've been down-voted without explanation, some people are like that here.  Your question might be a little vague with many possible reasons, for example your code is changing the values of different instances of the class. Could you show a more concrete example of the problem?

Comment: Is this maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568063/java-objects-of-classes-not-returning-the-same-values or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577693/java-having-multiple-objects-of-one-class?

Comment: Sorry, question is not clear.  In general in Java Class variables - are static and belong to Class. In opposite - instance variables belong to Object instance of class. What do you have? Then what code creates your object, what code changes it and how it runs? in another thread?, how your program get that object? ... and there could be much more questions about...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public class ClassA {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.setX(5);
        a.setY(7);

        int ax = a.getX();
        int ay = a.getY();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I was looking for, I have seen people use constructors to allow objects to hold variables being updated or something like that?

Comment: ClassA has 2 variables, x and y, that can be updated